# How to assign n things to k pools

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Can anyone please suggest dynamic programming approach to solve this problem?

Your neighborhood school district wants your help!
There are n school going children living in your school district and there
are k schools. Each child needs to go to a school that is at most 5 minutes
walking distance from his or her home. What this means is that each
child can attend only a subset of the k schools. Moreover, each school has
capacity; denote the capacity of the i-th school by ci
, and let the sum of
all the capacities be equal to n. Given data about the capacities, and the
list of eligible schools for each of the n children, the school district wants
to know if there is a valid assignment of children to schools. Design a
polynomial algorithm to answer this question.

Comment: Can you tell us what you're thinking and the code you've written so far?

Comment: post your code here so we can check what is going wrong

Comment: I'm thinking this problem is a version of multiple knapsack problem. But here, I just need an algorithm to understand.

Comment: I suggest you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem - this may not be a dynamic programming problem. If this is a set exercise or problem, it might be an idea to consider what subjects you have been taught - it's probably been set to check or exercise your understanding of something you have been taught recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> see [Max-flow min-cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem) (although not a DP approach)

- Connect `source` to all `N` children
- Connect all `K` schools to the `sink`
- Connect each child to all the schools with distance <= 5min
- Run flow algorithm
- If the `max-flow` is equal to `N` than there is a valid assignment

> Complexity

E.g. Dinic's algorithm runs in `O(VE log(V))` with in our case

`V` = `1 + N + K + 1`

`E` in [`N+K` - `N+K+(N*K)`]

- [List of algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem)